# Незадача с xws-security:3.0

Tags: java, gradle

Приветствую! В проекте очень нужно использовать библиотеку xws-security:3.0. Но при добавлении в dependecies выдает

```
Could not find javax.xml.crypto:xmldsig:1.0.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Users/s.slavin/.m2/repository/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0/xmldsig-1.0.pom
file:/C:/Users/s.slavin/.m2/repository/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0/xmldsig-1.0.jar
http://192.168.1.8:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0/xmldsig-1.0.pom
http://192.168.1.8:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0/xmldsig-1.0.jar
Required by:
com.company.project:pp-project:1.0-SNAPSHOT >     com.sun.xml.wss:xws-security:3.0
```

Как это исправить?
UPD. Нашел где американе фиксят это пользуя мавен, если что, вот ссылка https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31740919/how-do-you-replace-the-class-of-a-maven-dependency. Теперь вопрос больше состоит в том, как это реализовать с gradle. Может кто-то знает ссылку с пофиксенной либой?

**UPD** Пойдем другим путем. Подчеркнутая либа вроде нигде не используется, иначе была были бы проблемы с классами, а их нет. Проблема только в gradle, который не дает забилдится проекту. Как можно исключить эту либу? пытался exclude, но что-то как-то не вышло.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте [скачать оригинальную библиотеку](https://svn.code.sf.net/p/springframework/svn/repos/repo-ext/javax/xml/crypto/xmldsig/1.0/) и установить ее в локальный репозиторий. [Источник](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/63244-non-existing-dependency-javax-xml-crypto-xmldsig-jar-1-0?p=463807#post463807).

Comment: @enzo надо чтобы gradle сам скачивал с какого-то репозитория.

Comment: Похоже на то, что ваш доисторический артифакт потерли из Maven Central, и уже давно. Так что это удача, что где-то осталась ссылка на джарник. Но если вам уперся репозиторий, дело хозяйское. Удачи в поисках. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все оказалось просто. В build.gradle прописываем:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url 'https://svn.code.sf.net/p/springframework/svn/repos/repo-ext/'
    }
}

compile group: 'javax.xml.crypto', name: 'xmldsig', version: '1.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.wss/xws-security
compile group: 'com.sun.xml.wss', name: 'xws-security', version: '3.0'
```

Взял с http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.wss/xws-security/3.0 вкладка Gradle

Comment: Я от туда и брал. Так что это не подходит.